# How to include parent directory in RecursiveDir?

Tags: regex, msbuild

I'm trying to copy specific directories, saving the directory structure, but can't find a way to include specific sub-directories in %(RecursiveDir)

The one solution would be using a more general capture `.\**\Dir1\**\*.*`, but this might capture some unrelated stuff, such as Level1\Dir1, which is not correct for my task.

For now, i have to use all-inclusive `**\*.*`, then to remove specific directories from the item group.

Here is the script:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Files Include=".\Dir1\**\*.*" />
 <Files Include=".\Dir2\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyFiles">
 <ItemGroup>
   <Files Remove=".\**\.svn\**" />
 <ItemGroup>
 <Copy SourceFiles="@(Files)" DestinationFolder="..\OtherDir\%(Files.RecursiveDir)"
</Target>
```

The result is:

```
..\OtherDir\FileFromDir1.txt
..\OtherDir\FileFromDir2.txt
```

But i need:

```
..\OtherDir\Dir1\FileFromDir1.txt
..\OtherDir\Dir2\FileFromDir2.txt
```

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Can't leave this common issue unanswered...
the solution is adding an extra `**` prefix before the parent directory name:

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Files Include=".\**\Dir1\**\*.*" />
 <Files Include=".\**\Dir2\**\*.*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use DestinationFiles, not DestinationFolder, and can use an item transform to construct the path.

```
<Copy
  SourceFiles="@(Files)"
  DestinationFiles="@(Files->'..\OtherDir\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)')"
  />
```

Comment: The files from dir1 and dir2 are mixed in the OtherDir folder this way, aren't they?

Comment: No, the Copy task will match items from SourceFiles one-to-one with the corresponding item in DestinationFiles.  Since one is a transform of the other, each file in SourceFiles will have one-and-only-one match in DestinationFiles.

Comment: Please read the question carefully. This way it loses Dir1 and Dir2, and mixes them up under OtherDir.

Answer (score 0):

try changing %(Files.RecursiveDir) to

%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)

to give you

DestinationFolder="..\OtherDir\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"

Comment: I think it won't be suitable for DestinationFolder parameter this way

Comment: sorry i should have pointed out that it needed to use DestinationFiles